# npm run build failed in docker and tips: node node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build

Tags: docker, vue.js, vue-cli-5

```
[19:01:50] -  Building module bundle for production...
[19:04:41]  ERROR  Error: Command failed: node /root/workspace/frontend_DOJ3/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build
[19:04:41] Error: Command failed: node /root/workspace/frontend_DOJ3/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js build
[19:04:41]     at makeError (/root/workspace/frontend_DOJ3/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
[19:04:41]     at /root/workspace/frontend_DOJ3/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
[19:04:41]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[19:04:41]     at async /root/workspace/frontend_DOJ3/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:81:7
[19:04:42] [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[19:04:42] [ERROR] 193659402
[19:04:42] [ERROR] 1
```

This problem doesn't trigger every time. How do I fix this bug.

I tried to execute 'npm run build' locally. But that didn't happen.
So now I'm troubled.  Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.